# iPhone simple method definition and calling the current date/time

Tags: objective-c, datetime

I'm very new to iPhone development, and I'm trying to write a function which will accept one parameter, and return the current date/month and store it in a variable.

But I'm getting a (null) value with NSLog.

Method:

```
-(NSString *) getNowDateMonth:(NSString *)type {

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    if (type==@"month") {
        NSDateFormatter *monthFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [monthFormat setDateFormat:@"MM"];
        NSString *theMonth = [monthFormat stringFromDate:now];
        [monthFormat release];
        return theMonth;
    } else if (type==@"day") {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
        NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
        //int setDate = theDate;
        [dateFormat release];
        return theDate;
    }
    [now release];
    return NULL;
}
```

Calling the function to get value:

```
NSString *month = [self getNowDateMonth:@"month"];
NSLog(@"%@", month);
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, compare the strings using `[@"month" isEqualToString:type]`, because two strings containing the same text ("month") may not be equal by the `==` operator. `==` checks if they're *the same string object*, not *strings object with the same contents*.

Second of all, you're leaking the date when returning the month or day (not releasing `now`). You should use `[NSDate date];` instead of `[[NSDate alloc] init]`.

To sum up, a suggested better version of this method would be:

```
-(NSString *) getNowDateMonth:(NSString *)type {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    if ([@"month" isEqualToString:type]) {
        NSDateFormatter *monthFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [monthFormat setDateFormat:@"MM"];
        NSString *theMonth = [monthFormat stringFromDate:now];
        [monthFormat release];
        return theMonth;
    } else if ([@"day" isEqualToString:type]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
        NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
        [dateFormat release];
        return theDate;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Also, there are a few other points that can be taken into consideration to improve this method:

- do not use `NSString` as type; use an `enum`
- do not allocate `NSDateFormatter` on each call to the method; instead use a `static` variable in the method

Comment: This works perfect, adding [now release]; before return nil; line will release the now leak.

Comment: There is no leak! Adding `[now release]` will cause errors and/or exceptions! You do not `alloc` the `now`, you are getting an autoreleased object. Take a look here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) to reliably and easily extract unit information i.e. month, day, week etc from an NSDate.

See [Date and Time Programming Guide for Cocoa.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039)

Dates are a deceptively complex programing problem so Cocoa has a fully developed set of classes for dealing with them. However, the learning curve is a bit steep.